# How to Excluding Suborder Calculations from WooCommerce Analytics Report

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, report, analytics, revenue

How can we exclude suborder calculations from the WooCommerce analytics report? Currently, the report combines the main order value with that of suborders in the net sales figure, making it challenging to accurately interpret the net sales value in the WooCommerce analytics.

In the WooCommerce report, the revenue for last month appears to be accurate. However, there is a disparity when comparing this data with the information displayed in the WooCommerce analytics. Can someone provide insights into why these figures might differ despite both sources referring to the same timeframe?